# Find the Maclaurin series of the function $f(x) = 7 x^2 \sin 2 x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin series of the function

$f(x) = 7 x^2 \sin 2 x$

$(f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n) $

That is what is given on the question, we have to fill in $5$ blanks $c_3$ to $c_7$

The homework is past due, so I have the answers $(14, 0, -9.333, 0, 1.86667)$ but I'm not sure how to go about doing this... Can I use the expansion that we know for $\sin x$?

($x- x^3/3! + x^5/5!... $etc). If so... how exactly?

Side question: If it was just $\sin 2x$ I would replace all the $x$ in the expansion with a $2x$ instead, correct?

I'm desperate for help, I have a test tomorrow and i'm freaking out a bit...

Thanks.

Comment: $c_n= \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}  \forall  n  \ge  0 $

Comment: Take the expansion you know for $\sin(2x)$. You know how to do that, replace $t$ in the expansion of $\sin t$ by $2x$. Then multiply each term by $7x^2$.  So $c_0$ and $c_1$ will be $0$, as will $c_2$; $c_3$ should be $14$; $c_4$ will be $0$; $c_5$ will be $(7)\frac{2^3}{3!}$. Continue.

Comment: This may seem silly... but what is happening to the x's? What do I put in for those?

Comment: I have written out an answer, since answers provide more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you can find the Maclaurin series of a combination of "nice" functions by simple manipulations. Note that $\sin t$ has Maclaurin series
$$t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\frac{t^7}{7!}+\cdots.$$ 
For the Maclaurin series of $\sin(2x)$, replace $t$ everywhere by $2x$, and simplify a bit. We get
$$2x -\frac{2^3}{3!}x^3+\frac{2^5}{5!}x^5 -\frac{2^7}{7!}x^7+\cdots.$$
To find the series for $(7x^2)\sin(2x)$, multiply term by term by $7x^2$. We get
$$(7)(2)x^3 -(7)\cdot\frac{2^3}{3!}x^5+(7)\cdot\frac{2^5}{5!}x^7 -(7)\cdot\frac{2^7}{7!}x^9+\cdots.$$
Thus $c_0=c_1=c_2=0$. We have $c_3=(2)(7)$, and $c_4=0$. We have $c_5=-(7)\cdot\frac{2^3}{3!}$. and so on.

Comment: Omg thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. In principle you could also find the first $7$ derivatives of $7x^2\sin(2x)$ at $0$, and apply the usual formula. Not fun!